# NAudio stream Read method latency

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

I made my own beep code as an exercise. However it is lagging.

2-3 beeps lagging then 3rd or 4th comes quicker.

Can someone please explain why? And how do I rid off the latency?

I used bits from Mark Heath blogs and NAudio github code..

This is main console code:

```
var waveSine = new BeepStream(waveWhite.WaveFormat);
var sineChannel = new WaveChannel32(waveSine) { PadWithZeroes = false };

List<WaveChannel32> inputs = new List<WaveChannel32>();
inputs.Add(sineChannel);

var mixer = new MixingWaveProvider32(inputs);

var output = new WaveOut();
output.Init(mixer);
output.Play();
output.Volume = 0.5f;

while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    waveSine.Beep(1000, 150);
}
```

This is beep code (it basically outputs 0s, but when Beep is called it pushes cached sine samples):
*(note1: not production code so please ignore obvious inconsistencies)
(note1: in reality there are at least 2 channels - one is always playing, this is why I had to make second - the beep channel - also always playing. I would gladly write SamplesProviders instead but couldnt find good example)*

```
public class BeepStream : WaveStream
...
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    int beepBytesRead = 0;

    while (totalBytesRead < count)
    {
        if(playingNow == null)
        {
            // silence
            buffer[totalBytesRead] = 0;
            totalBytesRead += 1;// bytesRead;
        }
        else
        {
            // beep
            buffer[totalBytesRead] = playingNow[beepBytesRead++];
            totalBytesRead += 1;// bytesRead;

            if (beepBytesRead >= playingNow.Length)
                playingNow = null;
        }
    }

    return totalBytesRead;
}
```

An observation - Reads come with count 52920 always. What is this magic number? Can I reduce it? The wave format is float 44100 if that helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by simply trying everything.

Use of exclusive WASAPI output:

```
var output = new WasapiOut(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive, 3);
output.Init(mixer);
output.Play();
```